Change Mac address
I have read the NAND memory MT29F2G08ABAEAWP contents via the RT809F programmer from IP Camera,
when I have written the program (.bin) to the new NAND memory the Mac address and serial number of original camera has been copied to the new one.
When I have modified the Mac address and serial number from the buffer contents of the programmer then written to the new NAND memory the camera no longer works.
Please advise who can I change the Mac address and serial number manually without affecting the program?
Regards

why do you believe that the MAC address is the problem?

when connect the ip camera with duplicated mac address/serial number, the original camera will be disconnected.
